# How to update treepanel's root name without reloading the root again?

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, treepanel

I am working with `ExtJS 4.2` and have two tree panels. I am also using `treeviewdragdrop` to be able to drag some nodes from left tree to right.

[image]

**Now let me explain the problem I am having.**

You can see that `AMAZONE` is the `Service Alias` and as soon you change something in that textfield, there is a listener on `blur` to update right tree's `root text`. Since its AMAZON now, the root is also AMAZON. Then you can drag items from left to right like i have in the picture (Yhoo, dbTask).

This is when I get into trouble. When I go back and change the `SERVICE ALIAS`, it changes the name but nodes disappear since I have to reload the root node again in order to see the updated root text. Is there a way to maybe update the view, that actually updates whatever changed were made. This what I have now.

This is the code

```
listners:
{
    blur: function()
    {
        var root_node = right_tree.getRootNode();
        root_node.data.text = new_alias_name;
        right_tree.store.load(); // or reload()
    }
}
```

I know I can save dropped node into a variable and as soon as I reload the tree, I can assign those as children. But something tells me there should be simpler way. Thnaks ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

`root_node.set('text', new_alias_name');`

And remove the call to load.

Comment: Thanks, I knew there should be something simple. The funny thing is that I cannot find this function in `treepanel`'s method's list